# pause/play video javascript doesn't work in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'v search a lot for a way to pause/play a video when switching tabs and i try this code but it doesn't work 
there is no errors in the console and i can't find out what's the problem

```js
var video = document.getElementById("myvideo");
var documentTitle = document.title;

var updateTitleForVideo = function(state) {
  if (state === '') {
    document.title = documentTitle;
    return;
  }
  document.title = documentTitle + '[' + state + ']';
};

video.onpause = function() {
  updateTitleForVideo('Paused');
};

video.onplay = function() {
  updateTitleForVideo('');
}

document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
  var state = document.visibilityState;
  if (!video.paused) {
    if (state === 'hidden') {
      video.pause();
      updateTitleForVideo();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Typo: `document.visibilitycState` -> `document.visibilityState`

Comment: sorry! but no change even after i remove the c